# Overriding the redirect on saving force:createRecord on Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I need to override the redirect on save of a force:createRecord lightning component.

```
var eve = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
eve.setParams({
    "entityApiName": "Opportunity",
    "defaultFieldValues": {
        "AccountId" : accountId
    },  
    "panelOnDestroyCallback": function(event) {
        console.log('test');
        //console.log(event.getParam("id"));
        var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({
            "url": "<some visualforce page url>",
            "isredirect": "true"
        }); 
        urlEvent.fire();
    }   
});
eve.fire();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should mention `navigationLocation` also to stay on same page and then `panelOnDestroyCallback` will be called as callback function to do further processing.

**Note:** However inside the callback function of panelOnDestroyCallback, you will not have direct access to `component` and so as a workaround you can save `component` on `window` which you can access in callback function for other processing.

Sample code:

```
doInit : function(component) {
    window.component = component;
    $A.get("e.force:createRecord").setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Account",
        "defaultFieldValues": {
            'Name' : 'Test Account '+new Date().getTime()
        },
        "navigationLocation": "LOOKUP",
        "panelOnDestroyCallback": $A.getCallback((elem) => {
            console.log("panelOnDestroyCallback => ", elem, window.component);
            // let recId = component.find("v.recordId");
        })
    }).fire();
},
```